# Is there a way to obtain a count of instances where a criteria is fulfilled in a pivot table in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm analyzing a set of clinical data in Excel that includes

1. the level of care that a variety of individuals have received
2. the date of the receipt of that care
3. the date that the care ended

The question I'm trying to answer in a report is how many individuals that have received a higher level of care connected to a lower level within 14 days.

I've organized the data in such a way that by creating a pivot table, it organizes the data nicely. However, in this dataset individuals have had multiple instances of each level of care that may or may not be connected within 14 days to a lower level of care.

Granted, the dataset is small enough to count this out by hand, but I foresee having to do this many times in the future with possibly much larger datasets.

As such, I'm wondering if there's a way to automate this process. I can almost conceptualize a nested if statement to flag the instances prior to developing the pivot table, and then count these flags as follows:

as everything is already 2 way sorted by individual and then by date, I might be able to do if(levelofcare<>levelofcare of the cell above it, if(date of admission - date of discharge of the cell above it <=14,1),0 and then generate the pivot table and sum that column.

However, I feel this would be rather inaccurate considering the data and that sometimes, the "level of care" field isn't a standardized string.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be incredibly helpful if you were to post an example data set (with fake data, obviously) so users have a better idea of the information you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I would add columns to the data that calculate what you need to show in the pivot table.

Probably a column that shows individuals that received a higher level of care (an if statement that gives a yes or no answer). A column that shows if an individual received a lower level within 14 days if the previous column is yes.
These can then be added to the pivot.

Hypothetical answer as no data was provided in the question - happy to edit if data provided.